# sending GET Variable In ECHO META REFRESH

Tags: php, echo, refresh, meta

if i write this:

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.$_GET['w']"/>';
```

> error message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'w' (T_STRING),
>   expecting ',' or ';' in
>   /storage/ssd3/084/1533084/public_html/wikiscript2.php on line 12

if i change `'w'` to `"w"`

i get to wiki page but the title is like this.and ofcourse its a file not available there.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.$_GET[
```

what i am doing wrong here.Please help me.

i am trying to send echo meta refresh to the file like this.......`echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.$_GET['w']"  />';` it doesnt work this way.

Comment: Your problem are the quotes. Take a closer look where you use them and where you maybe shouldn't do so.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://php.net/string) for how to use strings in PHP.

Comment: i am trying to send echo meta refresh to the file like this.......echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.$_GET['w']"  />'; it doesnt work this way.

Comment: `echo 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'.$_GET['w'].'"/>'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your variable outside of the single quotes, like this:

```
 '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/'.$_GET['w'].'"/>';
```